# PowerShell FileInfo - Getting Custom Properties?

Tags: powershell

In the Windows Explorer I right click a DLL, choose Properties then the Version tab.

In the 'Other Version Information' area, under 'Item Name' there is a custom field called 'SVNBuildVerion'.

How can I retrieve that with PowerShell?

I've tried :

```
dir $targetDLL | select -ExpandProperty VersionInfo  | fl * -force
[System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($targetDLL) | fl * -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I think that example is produced for explorer by the SVN plugin extension for explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is an extended property.  Check out this [old blog post](http://keithhill.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!5A8D2641E0963A97!186.entry?wa=wsignin1.0&sa=761362006) that describes how to get extended properties for a file.

Comment: Thanks Keith, no go. I tried 

1..50 | % { "{0} {1}" -f $_, $myFolder.GetDetailsOf($fileobj,$_) }

There is an in-house C++ pgm they used from PoSh to get the custom attribute. If I get the source and work it out in PoSh I'll post it.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/VerPatch.aspx

This article seems to solve it. Anyone know of a C# version? They are looking for it too.